# How to I can show date in laravel blade from my table in this input field

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-6

How to I can show date in laravel blade from my table in this input field

```
   <div class="form-group">
      <strong>Date:</strong>
      <input type="date" name="date" class="form-control" value="{{ $productInovoice->date }}" placeholder="Date">
   </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should format the date to fix that.

try this:

```html
<div class="form-group"> 
  <strong>Date:</strong> 
  <input value="{{ $productInovoice->date->format('Y-m-d') }}" type="date" name="date" class="form-control" placeholder="Date"> 
</div>
```

or you can use the model attribute like below, put this function in your product model:

```php
public function setDateAttribute($value)
    {
        $this->attributes['date'] = Carbon::parse($value)->format('Y-m-d');
    }
```

Comment: ***<div class="form-group">
                    <strong>Date:</strong>
                    <input type="date" name="date" class="form-control" placeholder="Date">
                </div>*** My input field where I use type as a date filed so when I insert it on the datbase than t stored. So just now I want to display this date from my database tabel column.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
<input type="date" class="form-control" id="published_at" name="published_at" required value="{{ date_format(date_create($book->published_at), 'Y-m-d') }}">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="date" name="date" class="form-control" value="{{ $productInovoice->created_at->format('d M y') }}" placeholder="Date">
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can try this:**

```
<input type="date" name="date" class="form-control" 
       value="{{ date_format(date_create($productInovoice->date), 'd/m/Y')) }}">
```